# Filter one list by another using power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a list of elemental impurities in power query which I wish to filter according to whether or not they exist on another list known as the prop65 list.

The screenshot below shows a simplified example of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

I appreciate that using formulas However I don't know how to achieve this using a Power query solution. If anyone know how to achieve this it would be appreciated.

**Data shown:**

```
Aluminium 33.885
Antimony 0.6777
Arsenic 3.5064
Barium 2.259
Boron 1.3554
Bromoform 0.555
Cadmium 3.18895
Chromium 0.33885
Cobalt 1.1295
Copper 0.4518
Indium 0.4518

Simplified Prop65 List
Arsenic
Bromoform
Cadmium
Furan
Lead
Nafenopin
```

Comment: See if this [YT Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRd6wYkfDUQ) helps and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVZW1gCObHY) .. you can create another query to filter the first one.

Comment: Looks like you just want to merge the two queries using an inner join to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do that:

- Read in the two tables
- Do an `Inner` Join

```
let
    //get original data
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Data"]}[Content],
    data  = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Impurity", type text}, {"Amount (ppm)", type number}}),

    //get Filter
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Prop65"]}[Content],
    filter = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{"Simplified Prop65 List", Text.Type}),

    //Join them
    filteredData = Table.Join(data,"Impurity", filter, "Simplified Prop65 List",JoinKind.Inner),

    //Remove unneeded column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(filteredData,{"Simplified Prop65 List"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Another method would be a filter (`Table.SelectRows`) method, but it may be slower with a large dataset. At least, in a single instance where I had an opportunity to compare, the `Table.Join` method was faster on a 100,000 row data set.

```
let
    //get original data
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Data"]}[Content],
    data  = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Impurity", type text}, {"Amount (ppm)", type number}}),

    //get Filter
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Prop65"]}[Content],
    filter = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{"Simplified Prop65 List", Text.Type})[#"Simplified Prop65 List"],

    //filter the rows
    filteredData = Table.SelectRows(data, each List.Contains(filter,[Impurity]))
in
    filteredData
```